# What is best design pattern for handling rpc requests?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, rpc

I'm now developing a json-rpc project in C++. I've not decided yet how I handle rpc's requests. From the client side, server receives jsons like below.

```
{"method":"App1hoge", ...}
{"method":"App1fuga", ...}
{"method":"App2foo", ...}
```

The server side handles some applications, App1, App2, etc. So I think I should design *ApplicationRule* class for each class. In this case, *App1Rule* and *App2Rule* classes are needed. And I should also design ApplicationRuleManager for handle each rule. But I'm not sure how I design *ApplicationRuleManager*.

In general, how should I design the relationship between *ApplicationRuleManager* and each *ApplicationRule*? Strategy pattern is familiar with this case?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's very hard to say if "Strategy" or anything else is suitable until you have defined exactly what the responsibilities of "ApplicationRule" and "ApplicationRuleManager" are. (In my opinion, a "Manager" is often a code smell, especially if all you can say about it is "well, it manages things...")

Comment: Hard to tell what you're asking here. RPC already is a design pattern.